# How to assign unique names to images?

Tags: database, database-design, imagenamed

I'm writing a web application where users can upload images. I wonder what's the best practice of assigning unique names to images ? I thought MD5 can ben useful and enough, but since each image has an owner, do I have to use MD5 ? I mean it could be enough to rename with Userid + imagename + creationdate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database gives you a unique **ID** for each record. Though there are many different ways to do what you want, it is usually best to use this ID as a prefix/suffix to the name of the image. So, for these records:

```
ID  |  name
15    image.png
23    image.png
```

you could display something like: `15_image.png`, `23_image.png`

Comment: @Aleksi: you insert once, so it's not a big deal to ask it (if you want to save that way) and when you search, it's better to search by ID anyway.

Comment: I agree that it's not a big deal, but when you consider the users with lowest skill level, it is a bit misguided to tell them that the ID justs pops up. You have to design for it and create a sequence or an auto-increment declaration depending of the DBMS is in use i.e. you'll have to ask for it as it's not given.

Comment: @Aleksi: you're right, I haven't thought of it that way. I'll leave my answer as it is, though, until we see some more comments from the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not be enough as the user might want to upload several images with the same name.

The easiest solution is to use a sequence number with the image name. You can be certain that there is no other image with the same name and there will never be one. With a hash function there is always an ever so slight chance of collision.